# $.ajax() sends GET and POST request, but data not sent

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make an ajax request to check if username already exists on database, but I'm getting a strange behavior from it. Here is my script:

```
$("#username").blur(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "check_username.php",
            data:
            {
                username: $("#username").val()
            },
            success: function()
            {
                $("#username_taken").load("check_username.php").show();
            },   
        });
        return false;
    });
```

and my php:

```
<?php

    if (($connection = mysql_connect("database", "user", "pass")) === false)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    if ((mysql_select_db("database", $connection)) === false)
    {
        die ("Could not select database : " . mysql_error());
    }

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
        $check_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($check);
        if ($check_num_rows == 1)
        {
            echo "Username already exists.";
            return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

When I look on the network tab, I see two requests being sent, a GET and a POST, with the same info, I don't understand why. And my code doesn't work at all when I have

`if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")`

but if I try

`if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")`

it works and I have an error:

`Notice: Undefined index: username in check_username.php on line 20`

```
Line 20: $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
```

That is being passed in the data in the request, so I don't know why it doesn't recognize it. I really don't understand what's the problem with this because I have another ajax in that script that looks a lot like that one and it works perfectly...

Any thoughts??
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`load()` is a shortcut for :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
   ....etc
});
```

So you are first sending a POST request, and in the success handler of that POST request you're using `load()`, wich does the exact same thing but with a GET request, so you're calling the same PHP file two times, which is why you are seeing both a POST and a GET request.

Here's how you probably should be doing it :

```
$("#username").on('blur', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "check_username.php",
        data: { username: this.value }
    }).done(function(data) {
           $("#username_taken").html(data).show();
    });
});
```

And you should consider using PDO, as the old `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and not secure.

Comment: oh....I didn't know that about load....I don't really understand how that "done(function(data)" work....what I want to display is a message saying username is taken, but I don't know how to "connect" my php to script to do that...what's inside function(data)?

Comment: @MF - now you know, load() is a shortcut for $.ajax! The done function is the same as the success function in your code, and the data is whatever the PHP file outputs, in your case `echo "Username already exists.";` is what is returned to the done() function.

Comment: Oooh, so that's how you get stuff back from php!! This is perfect!! works like a charm!!! Thank you!!